# problem in sql case statement?

Tags: plsql

```
     select no        
     from  shan      
     where  account_number      = '7111'
     and   area          = 'O1139'
     and   ty            = '1'
     and   ty1           = 'T'
     and   date          = '12-AUG-10'
     and   code          in (case 'B'
                             when 'B' then 'j01','j05'
                             when 'C' then 'j02','j06'
                             else 'j03'
                             end);
```

i need to check code value in 'j01' or 'j05' , how can i rewrite the query anyone please direct me in a right way?

Answer (score 0):

```
select no from shan
where 
    account_number = '7111'
    and area          = 'O1139'
    and ty            = '1'
    and ty1           = 'T'
    and date          = '12-AUG-10'
    and ('B' = 'B' AND code in ('j01', 'j05') OR 'B' = 'C' AND code in ('j02','j06'))
```

case works for scalar values only.

The solution provided would be an alternative.

Comment: `(('B' = 'B' AND code in ('j01', 'j05')) OR ('B' = 'C' AND code in ('j02','j06')))` is more trusted as last line.